# Is CE 1.9.0.1 compatible with MySQL 5.7?

Tags: magento-1.9, database

My web host is currently planning to upgrade all servers from MySQL 5.6 to 5.7 next week (and just informed us today for the first time). I have done a little digging and have not found any real clarification if CE 1.9.0.1 runs on 5.7 or not, and from what little I have found, I am leaning towards the side of it not being compatible. So my question becomes, does anyone have any experience with 1.9.0.1 and MySQL 5.7 and if so, what precautions do I need to take, or is this just going to be a bumpy ride?

Comment: It's likely fine on a new Magento installation, but I would not upgrade an existing, live 1.9 shop to MySQL 5.7. See here for breaking changes in 5.7. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

Comment: Unfortunately that is the exact case, where they are upgrading our host and there is simply no stopping it. Do you see any changes within 5.7 listed in that document that would throw an error? I don't work much on the SQL side of things. :/

Answer (score 3):

Magento 1.9 is compatible with MySQL 5.7. You may have a bit of a bumpy start if you have to manually set the sql_mode parameters but in most cases it goes well.

I would heavily suggest however testing on a development server first so if you have to set the params manually you will know what to do as soon as the live version switches. You can take a dump of your database, install magento on the new DB then import the dump to get the best chance of no issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Francis , by possibly having to set the sql_mode parameters, are you referring to one specific change somewhere, or changing how some parameters act with the database entirely?

Comment: Its not one specific change no, you would need to test your Magento install to see if it produces any warnings - quite a few things in 5.7 have been changed so that a some warnings are now full errors. Fix the warnings and you are safe to go. There is query around that lets you check for warnings and another for having your install run like 5.7 (if its currently 5.6)